# How to test pinch events on a web page on a Macbook

Tags: javascript, macos, canvas, zooming, pinch

I am working on a website which has an canvas on it. I have an image in the canvas, and what I want to do is pinch to zoom the image (the web page will eventually be on a touch screen). I am using jGestures for detecting pinch event. However, I wonder if there is a way to test on a Mac computer, because when I do pinch on mac trackpad, it zooms the webpage, not the canvas, which means that the pinch on trackpad does not apply to my canvas tag, it zooms my webpage (the font, the width, the height). I also wonder if magic trackpad or magic mouse can do it. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Xcode you could run the iOS simulator. The simulator would allow you to pinch. Hold down Option key and you should be able to mouse click to zoom in and out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. However, testing a web page on a small iphone device seems a little bit troublesome. Is there a better way.

Comment: You can change your device type to iPad that should be larger.

Answer (score 0):

I got multitouch working on my MacBook's trackpad with npTUIOClient ([see article](http://smus.com/multi-touch-browser-patch/)) with an old version of Chrome. Think it was v.10 or so.